# What would be the software architecture of a videogame?

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture

I'm developing a videogame under Unity. I've been asked to describe the software architecture of my project. My videogame won't be using databases nor it will be connected to a server, it is a platform adventure kind of game with one player.

I have heard of other architectures like client-server, peer-to-peer, service-oriented, but can't find the one that truly fits a videogame.

Answer (score 0):

Without further informations nobody can help you. You need to tell us more about your game.

But I guess you program a multiplayer.

**Client-Server**

In short every player (client) will connect to a server and this server will mostly do all the work what happens in your game.

**Peer-to-Peer (P2P)**

Here, there will be only one host (server) and every client will connect on it. Because of this, there will be some problems if the host is far away from the clients and more. Basically if you are the host it is much easier to cheat because you are the server.

Comment: My videogame doesn't connect to a server nor it uses a database. Its style is adventure platform with one player.